# Disable PayPal Checkout Button using Smart Button Integration

Tags: paypal

I am using PayPal Smart Button Integration and I want only debit/credit option for payment, not PayPal checkout which redirects the user to PayPal. How can I disable PayPal checkout button?

I have gone through the disable fundings option but even there is no such information available to disable PayPal button.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to remove the PayPal button from the smart buttons checkout as that is a core requirement of the smart buttons checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever PayPal processes Debit/Credit Card payments, they also process PayPal payments as en equally presented option, so customers can choose their preferred one

There are some few exceptions like a merchant account with the Braintree gateway